# Pandas: Describing a single column while Masking

Tags: python, pandas

Code:

```
csv[csv["country"]=="US"].describe()
```

generates

```
>              points     price
>     count  10005.000   8633.000000
>     mean   88.566417   39.739836
>     std    2.666808    38.473267
>     min    80.000000   5.000000
>     25%    87.000000   18.000000
>     50%    88.000000   28.000000
>     75%    90.000000   50.000000
>     max    100.000000  595.000000
```

I want to generate the same info without the "price" column:

```
          points    
count   10005.000000    
mean    88.566417   
std     2.666808    
min     80.000000   
25%     87.000000   
50%     88.000000   
75%     90.000000   
max     100.000000
```

Should I combine the Boolean mask `csv["country"]=="US"` with this?

```
csv["points"].describe()
```

If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: just guessing `csv[csv["country"]=="US"].describe().loc[:,[['points']]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
csv.loc[csv["country"]=="US", 'points'].describe()
```